# Use the same variable in multi classes

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to make a list called coustmersList in customers Class, and I have another class called Reservation Class that needs to use customersList also. I was thinking of making this list static so I can use it anywhere. However, if I did this, it will not be encapsulated, and anyone can manipulate it easily.

So is there any solution?

Note* I am not allowed to use Database

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: I am working with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static method on the Reservation class which assigns the list and then on the static constructor of Customers set it.

```
public class Customers
{

    private static List<Customer> customersList;

    static Customers()
    {
        customersList = new List<Customer>();
        Reservation.SetCustomerList(customersList);
    }

}

public class Reservation
{
     private static List<Customer> customersList;
     public static void SetCustomerList(List<Customer> CustomersList)
     {
         customersList = CustomersList;
     }
}
```

If you want to ensure that customersList is initialized without caring if Customers has been called previously you can add a dummy function that is called from the static constructor of Reservations, that will ensure the static constructor of Customers is executed whenever you use Reservations.

```
public class Customers
{

    private static List<Customer> customersList;

    static Customers()
    {
        customersList = new List<Customer>();
        Reservations.SetCustomerList(customersList);
    }

    public static void Init() { }

}

public class Reservation
{
     private static List<Customer> customersList;

     static Reservation() { Customers.Init(); }

     public static void SetCustomerList(List<Customer> CustomersList)
     {
         customersList = CustomersList;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a CustomerComponent that has the Customers list. Inject the CustomerComponent as a dependency to the Reservations class. Expose methods like GetCustomer(id) or GetAllCustomers() in the CustomerComponent class and call those methods from the Reservations class.

```
interface ICustomerComponent
{
    Customer GetCustomer(int id);
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
}

public class CustomerComponent : ICustomerComponent
{
    private List<Customer> customersList;
    ...
}

public class Reservations
{
    ICustomerComponent customerComponent;

    public Reservations(ICustomerComponent customerComponent)
    {
        this.customerComponent = customerComponent;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var customer = customerComponent.GetCustomer(id);
    } 
}
```